# Spark Scala: How to use wild card as literal in a LIKE statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, wildcard, regexp-like

I have a simple use case.
I have to use a wildcard as a value in LIKE condition.

I am trying to filter out records from a string column that contains **`_A_`**.
Its a simple `LIKE` statement use case. But since **`_`** in **`_A_`** is a wild card, a `LIKE` would throw wrong result.

In SQL we can use ESCAPE to achieve this.
How can i achieve this in Spark?

I have not tried Regular expression. Wanted to know if there is any other simpler workaround

I am using Spark 1.5 with Scala.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.contains` (or) `like` (or) `rlike` functions for this case and use **`\\`** to escape `_` in **like**

```
val df=Seq(("apo_A_"),("asda"),("aAc")).toDF("str")

//using like
df.filter(col("str").like("%\\_A\\_%")).show()

//using rlike
df.filter(col("str").rlike(".*_A_.*")).show()

//using contains
df.filter(col("str").contains("_A_")).show()

//+------+
//|   str|
//+------+
//|apo_A_|
//+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Spark with Dataframe code would be as simple as

```
object EscapeChar {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = List("_A_","A").toDF()
    df.printSchema()
    df.filter($"value".contains("_A_")).show()
  }

}
```